# How to allow CloudFlare stream videos on localhost

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflarestream

I am unable to view a video served on `localhost:8000` (or `127.0.0.1:8000`). I tried the following allowedOrigins: `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `localhost:8000` and `127.0.0.1:8000`.

I get the `This video has not been configured to be allowed on this domain` error.

Answer (score -1):

Add the port like localhost:666
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cannot-see-videos-in-localhost/283779/2

Comment: This is something I tried, as explained in the post.